# Failed to compile entry-point @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (`es2015` as esm2015) due to compilation errors

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Can someone help me to solve these below-given errors?

I am upgrading my angular project from version 8 to 12. first, I was upgrading version by version "7 to 8, 8 to 9" but at version 9 I was getting so many errors, lots of incompatible dependence. I spent a lot of time on that did not work. so I tried to upgrade to the latest version. Now I am just getting these errors.

```
ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (`es2015` as esm2015) due to compilation errors:
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7538:37 - error NG1006: Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators
7538     starTemplate: [{ type: Input }, { type: ContentChild, args: [TemplateRef,] }],
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7559:47 - error NG6001: The class 'NgbRating' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'NgbRatingModule', but is not a directive, a component, or 
7559     { type: NgModule, args: [{ declarations: [NgbRating], exports: [NgbRating], imports: [CommonModule] },] }
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7332:7
7332 class NgbRating {
'NgbRating' is declared here.
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7332:7 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of NgbRatingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
Is it missing an Angular annotation?
7332 class NgbRating {
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7548:7 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of NgbModule, but itself has errors
7548 class NgbRatingModule {
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js:7548:7 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of NgbModule, but itself has errors
7548 class NgbRatingModule {
```

This is what I have when I hit "`ng --version`".

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.1  
Node: 14.17.0  
Package Manager: npm 7.20.5  
OS: win32 x64  
Angular: 13.0.0-next.1  
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms  
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic  
... router  

Package                         Version  
---------------------------------------------------------  
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.15  
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.901.15  
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.15  
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.1  
@angular/cdk                    12.2.1  
@angular/cli                    12.2.1  
@schematics/angular             12.2.1  
rxjs                            6.6.7  
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upgrade `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
whatever version you are on Angular select ng-bootstrap version according to that

run this

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
```

and the supported versions are:

```
ng-bootstrap    Angular Bootstrap CSS
1.x.x            5.0.2  4.0.0
2.x.x            6.0.0  4.0.0
3.x.x            6.1.0  4.0.0
4.x.x            7.0.0  4.0.0
5.x.x            8.0.0  4.3.1
6.x.x            9.0.0  4.4.1
7.x.x,8.x.x     10.0.0  4.5.0
9.0.0           11.0.0  4.5.0
10.0.0          12.0.0  4.5.0
11.0.0          13.0.0  4.6.0
12.0.0-beta.x   13.0.0  5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The update was not done properly.
You have to update with patience along with solving dependency issues.
Migrating to v9 would cause a lot of problems. So you might want to try solving the dependency issues first and then move on to higher ng versions.
If you do this with force flag, things might not work properly.